# Rich Editor that handles tab key

Tags: tabs, editor, key, wysiwyg, wysiwym

is there any web editor that actually handles tab input key?
By actually handles I mean it doesn't insert 4 blank spaces, or just ignore it.

I need it to type source code in it, so the tab key must behave nicely.
I also need to add basic functionalities, such as bold and italic.
I have tried all the big ones (TinyMCE, CKEditor, YUI Rich Editor, etc), but none of them seems to handle tab properly. I think this is browser issues...

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't any editor that handles a tab by inserting four blank spaces be trivial to modify so that is inserts a `'\t'` instead?

Comment: THANK YOU! I just needed a <pre>\t</pre> and it worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://writecodeonline.com/php/ does it...

It's also easy to implement on your own site.
If you need to type source code, that is a really nice one.

I used the setup he uses too in a similar way to be able to edit php content in my cms system.

Comment: Yea, well, so far it works for at least a year... I use that one all the time.

Comment: Yeah, and now the link is not working. +1 for NullPointer.

Comment: It was working last friday. I use it at work daily. The hosting provider of the site might be down momentarely.